# Offsetting a date based on time in excel using if and function

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, time, excel-formula

A confusing title, I know!

Let me explain in a little more detail.

A report I run is from 4am as opposed too midnight, so I'd like to offset dates with a time earlier than 04:00 by 1 (to make it a day earlier).

E.g. I run a report for 12/12/18 - I would get from 04:00 12/12/18 to 03:59 13/12/18 - I hope this makes sense.

I've been playing around with an IFAND statement:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR([@Time])>"00", HOUR([@Time])<"04", [@Time]="pm"), "yes", "no")
```

I've had little luck - every entry is "no"

Here is some sample data:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your formula requires all three to be true: Time after 00, time before 04, time = "pm". I would recommend removing `@Time]="pm"` for now. I don't see many situations that would resolve to a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
=IF([@Time]<4/24,[@Date],[@Date]-1)
```

as dates are stored as value like 43439 in excel  where 1 means 1 day since 1.1.1900 I believe (so 43439 is 5.12.2018) and hours are the same, only going from 0 to 1 because they represent only a single day then doing `<4/24` checks if the value in Time column is lower than 4:00.

If your time is as text in your Time column use

```
=IF(VALUE([@Time])<4/24,[@date],[@date]-1)
```

Comment: Worked a treat - I just had to change 4/24 to TIME(04,00,00) and boom!

You star!